# Python: How to calculate multithreaded download speed

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests

I wrote a multi-threaded http down-loader, now it can download a file faster than single threaded down-loader, and the MD5 sum is correct. However, I found the speed it showed is so so fast that I do not believe it is true value.[image]
Unit was not printed yet, But I am sure it is KB/s, please take a look at my code about the measure.

```
 # Setup the slaver
    def _download(self):
        # Start download partital content when queue not empty
        while not self.configer.down_queue.empty():
            data_range = self.configer.down_queue.get()
            headers = {
                'Range': 'bytes={}-{}'.format(*data_range)
            }
            response = requests.get(
                self.configer.url, stream = True,
                headers = headers
            )
            start_point = data_range[0]
            for bunch in response.iter_content(self.block_size):
                _time = time.time()
                with self.file_lock:
                    with open(
                        self.configer.path, 'r+b',
                        buffering = 1
                    ) as f:
                        f.seek(start_point)
                        f.write(bunch)
                        f.flush()
                start_point += self.block_size
                self.worker_com.put((
                    threading.current_thread().name,
                    int(self.block_size / (time.time() - _time))
                ))
            self.configer.down_queue.task_done()

    # speed monitor
    def speed_monitor(self):
        while len(self.thread_list)>0:
            try:
                info = self.worker_com.get_nowait()
                self.speed[info[0]] = info[1]
            except queue.Empty:
                time.sleep(0.1)
                continue
            sys.stdout.write('\b'*64 + '{:10}'.format(self.total_speed)
                + '  thread num ' + '{:2}'.format(self.worker_count))
            sys.stdout.flush()
```

If you need more information, please visit [my github respository](https://github.com/Page-David/wget-fast/tree/Page_David). i will be appreciate if you can point out my error. thanks.

Comment: `total_size += bunch.__sizeof__())` and `average = total_size/period`

Comment: @dsgdfg and each formula divide time?

Comment: @dsgdfg sorry for misunderstanding, but I need the 'current' download speed, not average.